# How to make highlighting text in WinDjView permanent?

Tags: highlighting, djvu

I study my university e-books by WinDjView program and I made **lots of** "highlight text" writing notes that is visible only by holding mouse on it. Now I see that if I copy the same file (book in WinDjView format) in another computer and open it all highlighted notes are gone! That is, only in a laptop that they are made they appear! My laptop is in a disaster status so if I want to recovery my laptop which has Vista-original on it and/or install a new Windows for it, many years of highlighting (which are my research notes) will be gone!

How can I make highlighting text in WinDjView permanent, i.e. in every computer be visible?

[image]

Comment: I don't use WinDjView, but search perhaps for a folder containing its data and copy it.

Comment: @harrymc, thank you for your reply, indeed. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way to do it. I am very primitive w.r.t. computers!